# react native code works inline but not when imported

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-2017

The following code works properly in react native 0.61.5.

```
// userApplication/screens/UserScreen.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button } from "./../components/arComponents";

class UserScreen extends React.Component {
    let COLORS = {
        INFO: '#11CDEF',
    }

    render{
        return (
            <>
                <Button style={{ backgroundColor: COLORS.INFO }} >Connect</Button>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

However, when trying to import the exact same object, I get the error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_constants.argonTheme.COLORS')`.

I have the following:

```
// userApplication/screens/UserScreen.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button } from "./../components/arComponents";
import { argonTheme } from "./../constants";  //This line changed from code above

class UserScreen extends React.Component {
    let COLORS = {
        INFO: '#11CDEF',
    }

    render{
        return (
            <>
                <Button style={{ backgroundColor: argonTheme.COLORS.INFO }} >Connect</Button>  //This line changed from code above
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the index.js file inside of the constants folder:

```
//  userApplication/constants/index.js
import argonTheme from './Theme';
export {
  // articles,
  // Images, 
  argonTheme,
};
```

And here is where the object is defined:

```
//userApplication/constants/Theme.js
export default {
  COLORS: {
    //LABEL: '#FE2472',
    INFO: '#11CDEF',
  }
};
```

How do I get the imports to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//userApplication/constants/Theme.js
export const argonTheme = {
  COLOR : {
    //LABEL: '#FE2472',
    INFO: '#11CDEF',
  }
};
```

And use below import

```
// userApplication/screens/UserScreen.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button } from "./../components/arComponents";
import { argonTheme } from "../constants/Theme.js";  //This line changed from code above

class UserScreen extends React.Component {

 render{
    return (
        <>
            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: argonTheme.COLORS.INFO }} >Connect</Button>  //This line changed from code above
        </>
    )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
//  userApplication/constants/index.js
import argonTheme from './Theme';
module.exports = {
  // articles,
  // Images, 
  argonTheme,
};
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that but I get the same error message. I've updated the question to include the error message.

Comment: I included the error message `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_constants.argonTheme.COLORS').`

Comment: can you try to import directly from ```/constants/Theme.js```

Comment: It works directly from Theme.js, but I'm trying to get it to work from index.js